# Why virtual event does not not call overridden handler

Tags: c#, events

Consider the following scenario, may be this scenario is very hypothetical

```
public delegate void MyDel();

public class T1
{
    public T1()
    {

    }
    public virtual event MyDel MyEvent;

    public virtual void RaiseEvent()
    {
        MyEvent();
     }

    protected virtual void HandleEvent()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("base event");

    }
}

public class T2:T1
{
    public override event MyDel MyEvent;

    public T2()
    {
        MyEvent += new MyDel(HandleEvent);

    }

    protected override void HandleEvent()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("overridden event");
    }
}
```

and main client code

```
        baseT = new T2();
        baseT.MyEvent += new MyDel(() => MessageBox.Show("From client"));
        baseT.RaiseEvent();
```

Why does it throw an exception, why virtual events do not behave like virtual/overridden methods?

Comment: did you read the message of the exception? what does it say?

Comment: @Botz3000 : :), I know what you are pointing to 'Object reference' but then why virtual overide possible in first place in terms of event if you can't get the virtual override behavior

Answer (score 1):

The interface of an event is really just a pair of methods, add and remove. A private backing delegate is generated for auto-implemented events that is accessible only inside the declaring class through the event's name.

The virtual keyword for an event only applies to the add/remove method pair. Accessing and invocation of the backing delegate is not virtual for an auto-implemented event. When the subscribe occurs on an instance of the derived class (`T2`), it is using the overridden add/remove methods which use its own backing delegate. The base class's backing delegate is still null and is still being invoked in `RaiseEvent`. This causes a `NullReferenceException` when `RaiseEvent` is called.

Virtual events are kind of rare. I would probably make the event itself non-virtual and use protected virtual methods to allow the derived class to modify the event's behavior.